# Why do Grafana ElasticSearch queries work when hard coded, but fail when using Grafana variable value substitution? and how to fix it?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

[image: Picture of Problem]

**ElasticSearch query works when hard coded, but fails when using Grafana variable value substitution:**

Query: +nginx.access.upstream.response: [*, 1**, 2**, 3**, 4**, 5**, 500]

 Each of these queries work when you hard code those values in the query.

```
Example Query: +nginx.access.upstream.response: 1** 
               ^That works shows a table of data instead of "No data to show"
```

Although that works, it's better to use a variable with 7 values allows you to use 1 panel to display the same data that could be put in 7 hard coded panels, so that you end up with a cleaner user interface.

The problem is now that you've switched the hardcoded values to variable populated values the query no longer works.

The plugged in variable values [* and 500] work

The plugged in variable values [1**, 2**, 3**, 4**, 5**] don't work / result in "No data to show" as seen above.

There's something funny going on when the values get substituted into the query. 

**Q1.) What's the best tool/method to debug the true value of the variable after substitution/Figure out why it' failing?** 

**Q2.) What's a method of fixing it/achieving the desired end result?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1.) What's the best tool/method to debug the true value of the variable after substitution/Figure out why it' failing?**

**Answer 1: Query Inspector**

 1** --when substituted becomes--> 1\\*\\*

 which explains why it didn't work

[image: A1.) Query Inspector]

**Q2.) What's a method of fixing it/achieving the desired end result?**

**Answer 2: What worked for me was to avoid using the special character * in the variable values.**
I rename the variable to HTTP Code Prefix and used the values [*,1,2,3,4,5]

 I then used the Query: +nginx.access.upstream.response: $http_code_prefix*

Comment: This is meant to be a knowledge share Q&A, but please let me know if there's a better solution to avoid the variable value being escaped when substituted.